# How to set recurence of per second in Microsoft Azure logic app using Office 365 connector

Tags: azure, office365, azure-logic-apps, azure-app-service-plans

I am new to Azure technology. I have created a custom logic app api connector which send SMS on getting Email from Office 365 connector. Here I could only select recurrence of 1 minute mininmum, but I need to set it minimum to 1 second. Even I r=tried to change my pricing tier to platinum - 3, I could not set it to per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current maximum for Premium is to recur once every 15 seconds.  If you need a trigger to occur more often than that, you would need to create an API App and code a push trigger which can occur as often as you like.

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: hey , a million thanks jeffhollan, u saved my world ! Is premium price tier only supports minimum recurrence of 15 seconds, which priceing tier should I use for minimum cost.?

Comment: You should be fine with Standard or even Basic -- depends on how many executions you anticipate per day.  But more details can be found here:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/